# redefinition of stdio with gcc -I

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I am trying to compile file with folloing command:

```
G:\cts\mingw64\bin\gcc -c G:\cts\test\10func-result\TestProject\test.c8\TestHarnessSource\test.c -I G:\cts\cts\include -I G:\cts\test\10func-result\TestProject\test.c8\TestCaseSource -w -g
```

However, it shows:

```
In file included from G:/cts/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:1007:0,
                 from G:\cts\cts\include/json_tokener.h:15,
                 from G:\cts\cts\include/json.h:25,
                 from G:\cts\test\10func-result\TestProject\test.c8\TestCaseSource/_ts_main_0.c:5,
                 from G:\cts\test\10func-result\TestProject\test.c8\TestHarnessSource\_testSuite_defs_.h:1,
                 from G:\cts\test\10func\test.c:12:
G:/cts/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h:178:26: error: conflicting types for '_fread_nolock_s'
   _CRTIMP size_t __cdecl _fread_nolock_s(void *_DstBuf,size_t _DstSize,size_t _ElementSize,size_t _Count,FILE *_File);
                          ^
In file included from G:/cts/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:1007:0,
                 from G:\cts\test\10func\test.c:1:
G:/cts/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h:178:186: note: previous declaration of '_fread_nolock_s' was here
```

`G:\cts\test\10func\test.c` looks like

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("hello world\n");
 
    return 0;
}
```

and `from G:\cts\cts\include/json_tokener.h`:

```
#ifndef _json_tokener_h_
#define _json_tokener_h_

#include <stdio.h>
#include "json_object.h"

#endif
```

How should I do to solve this?

I've tried new version of mingw64, but it now works

Comment: I doubt that you get the compilation errors with the code shown in the question. An error message refers to `test.c:12`, but the code in the question has only 6 lines. I don't see how `json_tokener.h` would get included. Please [edit] your question and fix this. See also [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Does removing the space between -I and dir path fix the issue ?

```
-IG:\cts\cts\include
```

Comment: No, the error info looks the same before